# I need to traverse through an 8 digit String to check some conditions in VB.Net

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio, integer

I need help in Vb.net, how can I traverse through an 8 digit integer and check whether

1. Three numbers r repeated consecutively like 111,222
2. Check whether numbers are consecutively spaced like 123,876 3. Check whether 4 numbers r present

I input the 8 digit as string as its a requirement then convert into a string.

```
Imports System.console

Public Class residentNumberCheck

    Dim cardNumber As String

    Public Sub inputNumberAndCheck()

        writeline("Enter the 8 Digit Resident Card Number")
        cardNumber = readline()

        While (cardNumber.length() <> 8)
            writeline("The Resident Card Number is Invalid. It does not contain 8 digits... Please enter again")
            cardNumber = readline()
        End While

    End Sub

    Public Sub sameThreeNumber()

        writeline("")
        writeline("...Checking for 3 consecutive numbers...")
        writeline("")

        Dim Num As Integer = Integer.parse(cardNumber)
        Dim temp As Integer = Num


        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim checker As Boolean = False

        While (Num > 0)

            i = Num Mod 10

            Num = Num \ 10

            j = Num Mod 10

            temp = temp \ 10

            k = temp Mod 10

            Num = temp \ 10

            temp = Num \ 10

            If (i = j And j = k) Then

                writeline("    ****The Number is a Special Number as the Number {0} occurs three consecutive times****", i)
                checker = True

                Return

            End If

        End While

        If (checker = False) Then
            writeline("The Number does not have 3 consecutive numbers")
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub ConsecutiveNumber()

        writeline("")
        writeline("...Checking for consecutive digits in increasing or decreasing...")
        writeline("")

        Dim Num As Integer = Integer.parse(cardNumber)
        Dim temp As Integer = Num


        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim checker As Boolean = False

        While (Num > 0)

            i = Num Mod 10

            Num = Num \ 10

            j = Num Mod 10

            temp = temp \ 10

            k = temp Mod 10

            Num = temp \ 10

            temp = Num \ 10

check1:
            If (i = j + 1) Then
                If (j = k + 1) Then
                    checker = True
                    writeline("    ****The Number is a Special Number as it has {0}, {1}, {2} consecutive numbers****", k, j, i)
                    Return
                End If
            End If
check2:
            If (i = j - 1) Then
                If (j = k - 1) Then
                    checker = True
                    writeline("    ****The Number is a Special Number as it has {0}, {1}, {2} consecutive numbers****", k, j, i)
                    Return
                End If
            End If

        End While

        If (checker = False) Then
            writeline("The Number does not contain consecutive digits in increasing or decreasing")
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub checksimilarfourdigits()

        writeline("")
        writeline("...Checking if a number is repeated four times...")
        writeline("")

        Dim Num As Integer = Integer.parse(cardNumber)
        Dim temp As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim checker As Boolean = False

        While (Num > 0)

logic:

            i = Num Mod 10

            Num = Num \ 10

            j = Num Mod 10

            Num = Num \ 10

check:

            If (i = j) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                temp = i
            Else
                temp = j
                GoTo logic
            End If

            If (temp = i) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                x = temp
                y = 0
            End If

            If (temp = j) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                y = temp
                x = 0
            End If

            If (counter >= 4) Then

                If (x = 0) Then

                    writeline("    ****The Number is a Special Number as the number {0} repeats four times or more****", y)
                    checker = True
                    Return
                End If

                If (y = 0) Then
                    writeline("    ****The Number is a Special Number as the number {0} repeats four times or more****", x)
                    checker = True
                    Return
                End If

            End If

        End While

        If (checker = False) Then
            writeline("The Number does not contain 4 equal digits")
        End If


    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub main()
        Dim user As residentNumberCheck = New residentNumberCheck()
        user.inputNumberAndCheck()
        user.sameThreeNumber()
        user.ConsecutiveNumber()
        user.checksimilarfourdigits()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Have you debugged your code to check if it is working?

Comment: it is working, but the output isn't the desired one

Comment: It can't be both. Either it is working and the output is correct, or not. Can you give samples of the numbers you've entered that don't work? Have you debugged to see where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compact your code you may use Regex class:

```
        Dim cardNumber As String = TextBox1.Text
' (\d) finds digit (\d)\1 finds digit repeated once, here \1 makes
' reference to first group (), this is, (\d)
' (\d)\1{2,} finds digit repeated at least 2 times
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = New Regex("(\d)\1{2,}").Matches(cardNumber)
        If mc.Count Then ' there are at least 3 consecutive equal #s
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("Number {0} occurs {1} times", mc(0).Value, mc(0).Value.Length))
        End If
        mc = New Regex("\d").Matches(cardNumber)
        ' each mc() contains one digit
        Dim incr As Int32=0, indI As Int32 = -1
        Dim decr As Int32=0, indD As Int32 = -1
        For i As Int32 = 0 To mc.Count - 1
            Dim curr As Int32 = Int32.Parse(mc(i).Value)
            If i < mc.Count - 1 Then ' there is a next number
                ' if current+1=next# =>increment count & save index
                If curr + 1 = Int32.Parse(mc(i + 1).Value) Then
                    If indI = -1 Then indI = i
                    incr += 1 : If incr = 2 Then Exit For
                Else
                    incr = 0 : indI = -1
                End If
            End If
            If i Then ' there is a previous #
    ' if current+1=previous# =>previous incr. count & save index
                If curr + 1 = Int32.Parse(mc(i - 1).Value) Then
                    If indD = -1 Then indD = i
                    decr += 1 : If decr = 2 Then Exit For
                Else
                    decr = 0 : indD = -1
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If incr = 2 Then
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2} Consecutive numbers", mc(indI), mc(indI + 1), mc(indI + 2)))
        ElseIf decr = 2 Then
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2} Consecutive numbers", mc(indD - 1), mc(indD), mc(indD + 1)))
        End If
```

Comment: Hi xavier, could you explain it a bit

Comment: also needed the count for the digits, if digits count is more than 4 it displays the count

Comment: It is there: in  mc(0).Value.Length